# How to return list of parameterized constructor in web method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I need to return list i.e,"List" in web method, but it is giving error like

> ApiClient.Model.Rate cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

I have tried to created parameterless contructor but its not working.

```
 public List<Rate> GetEstimateRates(string FromCountry, string FromZip, string ToCountry, string ToCity, string ToState, string ToZip, int PackWeight)
    {
        List<Rate> result = null;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               // related code
               estimateRequest.FromPostalCode = FroumCountry.ToString();
                try
                {
                    result = apiInstance.RatesEstimate(estimateRequest, apiKey); 
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    GetServiceError(e, "RatesApi.RatesEstimate");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WebMethodResult = ex.Message;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your Rate class?
Sometimes the error is misleading.

Comment: public Rate(string rateId = null, RateTypeEnum? rateType = null, string carrierId = null, so on);